# Call Public Property Declared in a ASPX Page from a Different ASPX Page

Tags: asp.net

How can I call a public property declared on a ASPX page from a different ASPX Page?  Is that possible?  It is a website project.  How can I get/call this property from a different aspx page?  I have attempted this from the other page, but it is not recognizing the partial class:  private Test_Default _test;   It does not recognize the "Test_Default"

I.E.

```
public partial class Test_Default : System.Web.UI.Page  
{  
    private string myAge = string.empty;  
    public string Name  
    {  
        get   
        {  
        return myName;   
        }  
        set   
        {  
        myName = value;   
        }  
}
```

Comment: This is not possible.  You have to pass a parameter in the query string or use some other method to get the information to that page.

Comment: It is a complex object.  How can I pass the complex object to the other page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a separate class exposing the property you are wanting to work with, and store the value in Session :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string MyName
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["MY_NAME"] != null)
            {
                return Session["MY_NAME"].ToString();
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
        set { Session["MY_NAME"] = value; }
    }
}
```

You should be able to call that from either Page.  If it's a complex object, then change the type from string to your object.

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a piece of shared code, create a class for it in the `APP_CODE` folder.

See MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx).